# PIC Low Voltage UART

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, microchip

I'm receiving data from SIM800L module to PIC 16F628A.
The problem is the PIC (PIC does not receive data properly from UART).It is working in home. But in site conditions It misses
lots of data. I guess its is due to 2.8V logic levels from SIM800L.

**UART connections as below.**

*PIC powered with a 3V3 regulator

*PIC TX --> 1K Resister--->SIM800L RX

*PIC RX <--- SIM800L TX

When the PIC pin is in UART RX it acts like a Schmitt Trigger Input. When I power the PIC from a 3V3
regulator can it detect 2.8V logic levels from SIM800L?

Is there any reliable method to obtain better reception to PIC UART?

[SIM800L Module](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enLK993LK993&sxsrf=APwXEddTt_Msuph7uE-i71emqWXLxdhBwQ:1686887570035&q=sim800l%20module&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj494zz8cb_AhULzTgGHUP1CmgQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1#imgrc=KdZ83JJp49MlsM)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many times when both ends use SMPS creates CM noise induced errors.  grounds are no longer 0V or noise becomes DM differential mode from lack of twisted pair or something.

Comment: Try UTP or STP wire , or linear supplies.

Comment: I'm using a PCB & there is no wires. & the circuit is powered from a transformer supply 2A.

Comment: Scope the signal quality and estimate 1.5V threshold and Vdd noise with AC coupled to 50 Ohms.

Comment: "The VCC pin is used to supply the positive (+) voltage to the module. Power supply 3.4V to 4.4V with min 2 Amp required to work the module finely. Remember, never connect it to a 5V power supply, which can destroy your module. Also, It doesn’t work on a 3.3 V power supply."  ??

Comment: UART (max. 2.8V) with threshold 1.4 to 1.5

Comment: For the entire circuit is powered from a 12V/2A transformer power supply. SIM800L is powered from a 4.2V (using LM2596 buck).& the PIC is powered from a 3V3 regulator.

Comment: if the environment is causing errors, is it an analog error?  or digital,?  (IRQ, overflow)  Try adding parity.

Comment: Does the Unit interface with anything else grounded like PC  or monitor or laptop with floating charger?. then try without charger. to eliminate CM noise from charger.  Either way a scope will be useful to debug.